# How to update a field value in array in mongo database?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can we update a value for 'Enabled'  field in Configuration at index 1 in Configurations Array in `mongo` database ?

Below is my `Json` data.

```
{
    "Configurations" : [ 
                           {
                               "Configuration" : {
                                   "Host" : "",
                                   "Port" : "1521",
                                   "Enabled" : "true"                 
                               }
                            }, 
                            {
                               "Configuration" : {
                               "Host" : "",
                               "Port" : "",
                               "Enabled" : "true"
                               }                                  
                            }
                        ],
    "Description" : "Check Database Server"                   
}
```

Is there any way to update value for Enabled field in Configuration ??
How can we update a value for `'Enabled'`  field in Configuration at index 1 in Configurations Array in `Mongodba` ?

I want to update Enabled field value of 2nd configuration in Configurations Array.

Comment: Please make sure only code is marked as code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Delete an element from the array which is present inside an object in Mongodb/mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797688/how-to-delete-an-element-from-the-array-which-is-present-inside-an-object-in-mon)

Comment: Array indices tend to be based on 0. And this reminds me of a MongoU question...

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this

```
db.collection.update({}, 
    { "$set": { "Configurations.1.Configuration.Enabled": false }}
)
```

Comment: Yes, I want something like this but what value we should pass for ... in the below code.  db.collection.update( ''....'', 
    { "$set": { "Configurations.1.Configuration.Enabled": false }}
)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.collection.update({
"Configurations": {
    "$elemMatch": {
        "Configuration.Port": "1521"
    }
}
}, {
"$set": {
    "Configurations.$.Configuration.Enabled": "false"
}
})
```